# How to create installable CD from customized running install?

Tags: debian, system-installation, iso

I have customized a copy of Debian to the point it's barely Debian. I want to be able to take the running install, which has all of my modifications and turn it into an installable CD. How would I do this? I've tried a lot of things, like simple-cdd, and created an install script with bash, neither of which worked. I don't want to abandon this since I've already put probably over 100 hours into it. Is there anything I can do?
Thanks!

Comment: use cloning software

Comment: Did you install everything via the package manager, or are there installs from source? Do you want the install-able CD to produce a system that can be upgraded e.g. via `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`? Do you want customized files e.g. ~/.vimrc or ~/.emacs.d?

Comment: @icarus The only thing I want is a small, not netinst CD. Yeah I do want customized files. The only thing is that this system is almost not debian at this point. I don’t really need the apt-get upgrade stuff, I’ll probably just upload new install/upgrade CDs to my site. I installed everything from package manager.

Comment: @jsotola I tried clonezilla, but what happened was the iso booted to grub-rescue (not the live, the one that clonezilla made)